# PostgreSql + Date Format Convert YYYY-MM-DD to Day, Date Month Year

Tags: postgresql, sql, date-comparison

Suppose I am storing this format in my postgre database table. Now I have to compare this date with one of the texbox value contain date in different format.

```
Database Date Format :: YYYY-MM-DD For example :: 2010-11-26

Text-Field Date Format :: Day, Month Date, Year :: Fri, Nov 26, 10
```

Now I have tried to compare this value but no response Plz suggest.

```
    Select * from table_name where user_id=('11') 
and to_char(effective_date, $$$$$$$$)=trim('Fri, Nov 26, 10');
```

Now Plz suggest which format should I use in place of $$$$$$$$ ???

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table_name 
WHERE 
  user_id=('11') 
AND 
  to_char(effective_date, 'Dy, Mon DD, YY') = trim('Fri, Nov 26, 10');
```

Answer (score 8):

This should do it: `to_char(effective_date, 'Dy, Mon DD, YY')`

Btw: this is all documented in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html